# String parsing issue in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am getting issue while parsing string. I have tried replace to remove unwanted words from the string it didn't work for me. I have tried

```
String tadData=tag; // it contains that string
tadData.replaceAll("\\<!--.*?\\-->", "");
```

I need to remove the  words between `<!--      -->` this tag.

String is present in below image.

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: _standard advice not to use regex for xml parsing_

Comment: `String#replaceAll(regex,replacement)` will replace the entire regex with replacement , So your `<!-- -->` will also get replaced

Comment: i have tried this one also but still not replacing data

Comment: you need to keep  these tags `<!-- -->` intact or not ?

Comment: i just want to remove the data between these tags. i don't have any problem if these tags are present in string. But data should not be their in tags.

Comment: then my friend your code is perfect just use 
`(str.replaceAll("\\<!--.*?\\-->", "<!-- -->"));` , if want to keep tags intact !
**[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/GZUdRT)**

Comment: If my String is in one line only then it works .in this scenario string is divided into multiple lines as i shown in image. may be that's the reason its not replacing.Is their any to do this.

Comment: it replaced only first line. Din't work for the other lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73056/discussion-between-addy-and-neeraj-jain).

Answer (score 0):

```
tadData.replaceAll("(<!--)(.*?)(-->)", "$1$3");
```

This line will divide your string into 3 groups.Using the second argument,u can get any of the group.

Means,First line will give you output as (becasue of grouping $first and third groups).

```
tadData.replaceAll("(<!--)(.*?)(-->)", "$2");
```

This line will give u the String between the strings ""

Comment: Can u tell me the expected output fromt he above question?

Comment: **For Input** `<!-- The Comment Which needs to Be Removed --> OK` ***the output should be***  `<!-- --> OK`

Comment: so,tadData.replaceAll("(<!-- )(.*?)(-->)(.*?)", "$1$3$4"); will give u the same output as required.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex thing is optional, I tried this by checking file line by line as follows,

```
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File("path_and_file_name");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    boolean found = false;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.matches("(.*)<!--(.*)") && line.matches("(.*)-->(.*)")) { //complete comment in one line so found is false.
            found = false;
            lines.add("<!-- -->"); //remove if you dont want to print <!-- -->
        } else if(line.matches("(.*)<!--(.*)")) { //starting tag is found so found is true.
            found = true;
        }
        else if(line.matches("(.*)-->(.*)")) { //after finding end tag found is false. 
            found = false;
            lines.add("<!-- -->"); //remove if you dont want to print <!-- -->
        } else { //if there are no any <!-- or --> tag 
            if(found == false) {//check if starting tag (<!--) has found.
                lines.add(line); //if not added to lines.
            }
        }
    }

    for(String s: lines) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

input file

```
ewvfvwoirvorwijvriob
revbgebvgeiogeb
grbvgebv
gebg
bgbvgetbgtebgt
<!--abcdef-->
powdjciofwevrv
vrwebvr

<!-- 
wfpvjnfwpvg vhbrebiuge
-->

wfevfoienrfevoeigb

<!--

ewopvifweopvoifewvjw
weifjrweniovijovw
ewfvfewv

-->
```

output

```
ewvfvwoirvorwijvriob
revbgebvgeiogeb
grbvgebv
gebg
bgbvgetbgtebgt
<!-- -->
powdjciofwevrv
vrwebvr

<!-- -->

wfevfoienrfevoeigb

<!-- -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
tadData.replaceAll("\\<!--.*\\-->", "");
```

If you want to match the word between the tags then use this regex

```
\<!--(.*?)\-->
```

**EDIT:-**

If you want to keep the tags then simply replace the `""` with the `"<!-- -->"` ie.,

```
tadData.replaceAll("\\<!--.*\\-->", "<!-- -->");
```

or your own code only with a small change

```
tadData.replaceAll("\\<!--.*?\\-->", "<!-- -->");
```

Comment: this will not only  remove  words in between but also thses tags `<-- -->`

Comment: and now you copy my answer!! nice! :)

Comment: @Mahdad:- What? :O Are you crazy?

Comment: @NeerajJain:- Probably my guess but I think OP wants to remove the comments tag from his page. But that is my guess only

Comment: @Rahul then I think his code is perfect , **[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/GZUdRT)**

Comment: @NeerajJain:- Yes I just saw the comments!  Perfect!